# Example to throw a BufferError

Tags: python, python-3.x

On reading in the Python 3.3 documentation I noticed the entry about a BufferError exception: "Raised when a buffer related operation cannot be performed.". Now I'm wondering in which cases code could throw this error to determine if it is due to a programming error or more like a sort of a system error. Has somebody an example for this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the functions that might raise a BufferError:

http://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/buffer.html#buffer-related-functions

Comment: As I'm seeing it does this mean that only code written in a higher language like an external library or the Python interpreter itself can throw this exception due to an internal error?

Answer (score 1):

Most exceptions are actually more applicable to C-code than Python code using the buffer protocol; see the [C API buffer protocol](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects).

From the 3.3 source code, I see the following error messages being used for `BufferError`:

*`memoryview`*:

- *underlying buffer is not writable* for a read-only buffer.
- *writable contiguous buffer requested for a non-contiguous object.* for a memory view that is not using the right contiguous format
- *memoryview has %zd exported buffer%s* on release; this would, IIRC, indicate that the reference count off.
- *memoryview: underlying buffer is not writable* when creating a writable `memoryview` from a read-only buffer. Should not happen from Python code.
- *memoryview: underlying buffer is not C-contiguous* when passing in a non-contiguous buffer object but flags requested one. If strides are used and the buffer is not C-contiguous, this exception is also thrown.
- *memoryview: underlying buffer is not Fortran contiguous*, ditto.
- *memoryview: underlying buffer is not contiguous*, ditto.
- *memoryview: underlying buffer requires suboffsets*: flags indicate that a suboffset buffer is required but the buffer passed is not.
- *memoryview: cannot cast to unsigned bytes if the format flag is present*: unsigned bytes and a specified format do not mix.

*`bytearray`*:

- *Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized*: attempting to resize a `bytearray` that has other views on it.

There is also a undocumented `PyObject_CopyData` C-API method that'll throw this exception with *destination is too small to receive data from source* if the destination buffer is too small.